# Android NFC <tech-list> - problem

Tags: android, nfc

id want to write my first NFC-application on android. For this i use the android developers link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html

Here for specifying the supported technologies you have to create a xml file like this:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

My problem is, at the  tag i get following error: "error: Found tag tech-list where item is expected"

The target of my application is 2.3.3. I think this has to work on this target ...

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: i've solved now the problem. the cause was the wrong folder in which i saved the xml file ... don´t do this directly in the "values" folder!

Comment: You should answer your own question.

Answer (score 6):

Snippet from my app's AndroidManifest.xml file for the activity that receives NFC intents

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.ClientActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:description="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ttlogo">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter"
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.ttag.be" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The file containing the filter definition is in res/xml/nfc_tech_filter.xml and looks like this

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<!--  Touchatag tag -->
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>        
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
</tech-list>
<!--  DESFire tag -->
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>        
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
</tech-list>
<!--  Any Tag -->
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>        
</tech-list>
```

Comment: Thank you, with a slight modification, that saves my day. I simply have to read a tag with an application like "NFC TAgInfo" and it gives me data to write the correct tech-list.

Comment: What about **NfcV**?

Answer (score 5):

The android SDK doc tell:
Save this file (you can name it anything you wish) in the

```
 <project-root>/res/xml/
```

folder.

so,you probably save your xml file in an wrong folder.(did you save it in `<project-root>/res/values/` )

Answer (score 2):

Put each of the `<tech>` item in a separate `<tech-list>` node.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to create the directory `xml` inside `res`. 
It was not very clear for me. Hope it helps someone.