# Is there a way to write an intent filter to catch a TNF_UNKNOWN NdefMessage?

Tags: android, nfc

Most of the examples I have seen online use a TNF_MEDIA_TYPE with a mime type filter to route the NFC initiated Intents to the correct activity. 
But I could not find any suitable way to catch TNF_UNKNOWN NdefMessage with a custom binary payload.

Any suggestion?

Ref:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html#TNF_UNKNOWN

Comment: You might want to avoid using `TNF_UNKNOWN` for your application. `TNF_UNKNOWN` is not intended to be used for creating NDEF records. It is rather meant as a means to skip records from parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer :
I think the answer is here : [Android NFC tech-list - problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841470/android-nfc-tech-list-problem)

In fact, I am using the TNF_UNKNOWN for my own tags and everything worked well in Android 4.1.2
But when it comes to Android 4.3 then the `<intent-filter>` does not work.
So I had to find a correct filter and especially the right `<tech-list>` resource file.

In my case, I went to this slightly modified xml file (Topaz 512 added) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" >
  <!-- Touchatag tag -->
  <tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
  </tech-list>
  <!-- DESFire tag -->
  <tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
  </tech-list>
  <!-- TOPAZ tag -->
  <tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
  </tech-list>
  <!-- Any Tag -->
  <tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
  </tech-list>
</resources>
```

And the same manifest entry :

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
</intent-filter>
<meta-data
  android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter"
  android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
```